# How to do a catch all in Slim framework?

Tags: php, frameworks, slim

I'm making a short URL service using Slimphp to take care of my routing. I can define any route just fine but if I want to react to `/<code here>` instead of that taking me to the index page of the project.

This is my code:

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use ShortUrls\ShortUrls;


error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', true);

$app = new \Slim\Slim();(array(
    "view" => new \Slim\Views\Smarty()
));


$view = $app->view();
$view->parserDirectory        = dirname(__FILE__) . 'vendor/smarty/smarty/libs';
$view->parserCompileDirectory = dirname(__FILE__) . '/compiled';
$view->parserCacheDirectory   = dirname(__FILE__) . '/cache';
$view->setTemplatesDirectory(dirname(__FILE__) . '/lib/templates/');

\ShortUrls\Config::init_config();

$app->get('/', function ($hash) {
    try {

    } catch (ResourceNotFoundException $e) {
        echo '404';
    }
    $short = new ShortUrls();
    if ($hash) {
        if ($short_url = $short->get_url_by_hash(($hash))) {
            print '<pre>';
            print_r($short_url);
            print '</prE>';
        }
    } else {

        $short->create_short_url("http://www.locovsworld.com");
        // $app->render('layout.tpl', array('test' => 'Hello'));
    }
    global $app;
    print_r( $app->request()->params() );
    echo 'done';
});

$app->run();
```

Remember `/ == index /9082ABC` could be a short URL that I have to query from the database and redirect the client to.

Answer (score 3):

I already got the answer its the following ...

```html
$app->get('/(:hash)', function ($hash) {

};
```

I am sorry to bother you guys :(